# Akka stream get current value of an infinite stream from outside world

Tags: akka, akka-stream

What is the best way to get the current value of an infinite stream which aggregates values and by definition never complete

```
Source.repeat(1)
  .scan(0)(_+_)
  .to(Sink.ignore)
```

I would like to query from Akka HTTP the current counter value. Should I use dynamic stream ? The broadcastHub  and then from Akka http subscribe to the infinite stream on GET request ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution could be to use an actor to keep the state you need. `Sink.actorRef` will wrap an existing actor ref in a sink, e.g.

```
class Keeper extends Actor {
  var i: Int = 0

  override def receive: Receive = {
    case n: Int ⇒ i = n
    case Keeper.Get ⇒ sender ! i
  }
}

object Keeper {
  case object Get
}

val actorRef = system.actorOf(Props(classOf[Keeper]))

val q = Source.repeat(1)
  .scan(0)(_+_)
  .runWith(Sink.actorRef(actorRef, PoisonPill))

val result = (actorRef ? Keeper.Get).mapTo[Int]
```

Note that backpressure is not preserved when using `Sink.actorRef`. This can be improved by using `Sink.actorRefWithAck`. More about this can be found in the [docs](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/stream-integrations.html?language=scala#sink-actorrefwithack).

Comment: Isn't there any problem with parallelism and unorder messaging to actors ?

Comment: There is no parallelism involved in the example above. You send messages sequentially to the actor, and the actor processes them sequentially. Ordering of the messages is guaranteed by Akka on a per-sender basis.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is using [Sink.actorRefWithBackpressure](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/operators/Sink/actorRefWithBackpressure.html).

Imagina having the following Actor to store the state coming from a Stream:

```scala
object StremState {
  case object Ack
  sealed trait Protocol                         extends Product with Serializable
  case object StreamInitialized                 extends Protocol
  case object StreamCompleted                   extends Protocol
  final case class WriteState[A](value: A)      extends Protocol
  final case class StreamFailure(ex: Throwable) extends Protocol
  final case object GetState                    extends Protocol
}

class StremState[A](implicit A: ClassTag[A]) extends Actor with ActorLogging {
  import StremState._

  var state: Option[A] = None

  def receive: Receive = {
    case StreamInitialized =>
      log.info("Stream initialized!")
      sender() ! Ack // ack to allow the stream to proceed sending more elements

    case StreamCompleted =>
      log.info("Stream completed!")

    case StreamFailure(ex) =>
      log.error(ex, "Stream failed!")

    case WriteState(A(value)) =>
      log.info("Received element: {}", value)
      state = Some(value)
      sender() ! Ack // ack to allow the stream to proceed sending more elements

    case GetState =>
      log.info("Fetching state: {}", state)
      sender() ! state

    case other =>
      log.warning("Unexpected message '{}'", other)

  }
}
```

This actor can be then used in a Sink of a Stream as follows:

```scala
    implicit val tm: Timeout           = Timeout(1.second)
    val stream: Source[Int, NotUsed]   = Source.repeat(1).scan(0)(_+_)

    val receiver = system.actorOf(Props(new StremState[Int]))
    val sink = Sink.actorRefWithBackpressure(
      receiver,
      onInitMessage = StremState.StreamInitialized,
      ackMessage = StremState.Ack,
      onCompleteMessage = StremState.StreamCompleted,
      onFailureMessage = (ex: Throwable) => StremState.StreamFailure(ex)
    )

    stream.runWith(sink)
    // Ask for Stream current state to the receiver Actor
    val futureState = receiver ? GetState
```